# How to start Service from Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I have class Main_Thread:

```
public class Main_Thread extends Thread {
...
}
```

How can i start Android service into Main_Thread , like this:

```
startService(new Intent(this, Main_Service.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

on this code:

```
  startService(new Intent(this, Main_Service.class));
```

`this` is a reference to the activity, which is a context, which have a reference to the ApplicationContext.

For that line to work you have to give an ApplicationContext reference to the thread and call:

```
  startService(new Intent(context, Main_Service.class));
```

Comment: I get next error: The method startService(Intent) is undefined for the type Main_Thread

Answer (score 0):

if you have a context reference:

```
startService(new Intent(context, Main_Service.class));
```

else if you declare the thread in the same class that an Activity:

```
startService(new Intent(YourActivity.this, Main_Service.class));
```

else if you know that it's the actual activity you can do it:

```
startService(new Intent(ActualActivity.class, Main_Service.class));
```

Comment: I get next error: The method startService(Intent) is undefined for the type Main_Thread